# VB Recursion and Fibonacci sequence

Tags: vb.net, recursion

OK. I know this is a classic but I cant seem to find any threads explaining how the trace table would work. My own attempts look like faulty logic. For example this code works great:

```
 Sub Main()
        For i = 1 To 6
            Console.WriteLine(f(i))
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
 End Sub
```

Then we have the Function:

```
Function f(n)
        If n <= 1 Then
            Return n
        Else
            n = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
            Return n
        End If
    End Function
```

However, my trace table ends up like this:

```
i  f-1  f-2  n
1            1
2   1    0   1
3   2    1   3
4   3    2   5
5   4    3   7
6   5    4   9
```

Which makes perfect sense to me, but obviously shows I dont have a clue. What is the faulty logic here??

Comment: "Which makes perfect sense to me, but obviously shows I dont have a clue" - That statement is very contradictory. I am not sure what your question actually is. Do you just want to know how the trace table works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace table makes no sense since the `f-1` column should be named `f(n-1)` and currently only shows `i-1`.

If I fix a few of the mistakes you have made, I obtain the following piece of code (highlighted in boldface):

```
Public Module modmain

Function f(n) As Integer
    If n <= 1 Then
        Return n
    Else
        n = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
        Return n
    End If
End Function

 Sub Main()
        For i as Integer = 1 To 6
            Console.WriteLine(f(i))
        Next
        Console.ReadKey()
 End Sub

End Module
```

I obtain the correct output for the first six Fibonacci elements:

```
$  vbnc fib.vb 
Visual Basic.Net Compiler version 0.0.0.5943 (Mono 4.0.1 - tarball)
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Rolf Bjarne Kvinge. All rights reserved.

A warning message should have been shown: 'Parameter type should be specified.'
Assembly 'fib, Version=0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' saved successfully to '/home/kommusoft/testfolder/fib.exe'.
Compilation successful
Compilation took 00:00:00.7312840
$ mono fib.exe 
1
1
2
3
5
8
```

For the trace table, you have to rename your columns such that they look like:

```
i  f(i-1)  f(i-2)  f(i)
```

Now for the first two `i`s (`i=0` and `i=1`) you can simply fill in `0` and `1` in the last column:

```
i  f(i-1)  f(i-2)  f(i)
0                     0
1                     1
```

Now for the next row, `f(i-1)` and `f(i-2)` can be looked up in the part of the table you already filled in:

```
i  f(i-1)  f(i-2)  f(i)
0                     0
1                     1
2       1       0     1
```

```
i  f(i-1)  f(i-2)  f(i)
0                     0
1                     1
2       0       1     1
3       1       1     2
```

etc.

Comment: @Wilhelm Van Onsem thank you for the detailed response. How did you get f(i-1) to be 1 when i is 3? Surely 3-1 is 2??  I think this is at the heart of my problem

Comment: `3-1` is indeed `2`, so then you look up `f(2)` (the right column of row `i=2` which is `1`.